# Are there any HTTP/HTTPS interception tools other than Fiddler, Charles, Poster, and Achilles?

Tags: security, http, testing, https

I'm in the process of testing my application with respect to security.

Aside from [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) (Firefox plug in).  Are there any other free to use https interception (and editing) applications out there?  Especially ones which can be installed w/o admin privileges.

Achilles comes to mind, but I don't think it can handle https traffic.

Comment: FWIW, you can xcopy-deploy Fiddler; it doesn't actually require admin.

Comment: haha cus ur topic i got to know few more like these now ;) ty

Comment: There's an open-source alternative now: https://github.com/james-proxy/james

Comment: James Proxy is now unmaintained - they recommend [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/) instead, which is also open-source & doesn't require admin privileges for install or interception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Achilles does work on HTTPS traffic, but they note on their site that it is not the best tool any more.

Their suggestions are [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) and [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) both of which I highly recommend.

Comment: +1 for burp suite.  Highly effective, intuitive, and free.

Comment: Instead of [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) should use [ZAProxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project). See first link for info.

Answer (score 10):

[OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP) - its free, open source and cross platform.

Its also the most active open source web security tool and came first and second in the last 2 'Top Security Tools' surveys run by Toolswatch.org ([2013](https://www.toolswatch.org/2015/01/2014-top-security-tools-as-voted-by-toolswatch-org-readers/), [2014](http://www.toolswatch.org/2013/12/2013-top-security-tools-as-voted-by-toolswatch-org-readers/))

It was originally forked from Paros, which is no longer maintained, but it now has loads more functionality.

Its an OWASP Flagship project having replaced WebScarab, which is also essentially no longer maintained.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is amazing. It captures everything on the network so you'll need to filter down to http/https: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters.

Comment: As-is Wireshark isn't able to display https traffic (you need to [provide the SSL/TLS key apart](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS))

Answer (score 2):

There are a few programs that I would suggest.

Paros Proxy and Ratproxy have already been noted.

[scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is a powerful packet manipulation tool, and has all of the sniffing and monitoring capabilities as well.
[dsniff](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) is a suite of tools that allows manipulation, injection, and all sorts of interception and modification options.

There is also a plugin for IE called [Tamper IE](http://www.bayden.com/TamperIE/) that has a simple GUI based packet editor.

All of these are free.

Comment: +1 for scapy.  An awesome low-level packet inspection library for Python.

Answer (score 1):

Doing more research I came across [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/).  Seems to be a good alternative to the
 others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/). I believe the basic version is free and captures your HTTPS traffic to some extent. The Professional version is worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ratproxy](http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/).  It may not be exactly what you're asking for, but is very useful in testing the security of your web app.

Rather than intercepting HTTP and allowing you to edit or replay requests, it installs as a proxy and monitors the normal use of your web app, and then provides a report on possible security issues, along with their severity.  It can also be configured to attempt active XSS or XSRF attacks where it thinks there is a vulnerability.

The site says "Ratproxy is currently believed to support Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS X, and Windows (Cygwin) environments" but I've only used it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com)

It is proxy-less solution and have zero impact to the transferring data.

Also it has modern user  interface :)

Comment: Just for feature readers coming across this page: 'modern user interace' means a ribbon clone in this case (ala Microsoft Office)...

Comment: not only :) 
It comes with a 'report control' that allows group, filter and sort http sessions and get some quic statistics for selected sessions (size by domains, by content types, gzip statistics, etc).
Did you ever run it before posting your comment about ribbon?